# how to validate name which should accept below 20 characters, it should not get empty using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, my objective is to validate the Store Name, Neither it should be empty nor exceed more than 20 characters. it should show the error message before clicking on Submit Button.
I want to handle this validation in Handle change function. I've tried but not sure whether it is correct or not. I know this Query might be a simple one but i couldn't able to figure it out as i was new to this.

Here is the code:

```
  onChange= (name, value) => {
    // this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    let errors = this.state.errors;
    if (!value || value.length === 0) {
      errors[name] = "Store Name is required";
    } else if (value.length > 20) {
      errors[name] = "Store Name should not increase 20 characters";
    } else {
      errors[name] = "";
    }
  };
```

Can anyone please help me in this query?

Comment: Just write a couple of unit tests with different cases which you expect and see if it satisfies you.

Comment: you have to add `onChange={(e) => this.setState({storeName: e.target.value})}` to TextInput

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress - I want to show errors while exceeding 20 characters and if user clicks on submit without writing anything in input field

Comment: @Arunya, Hope this is what you want, https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-curran-8uge2

Comment: [displaying form errors in react with react-bootstrap](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-wilbur-pxwym?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your onChange.

```
onChange = ({name, value}) => {
  let errors = {...this.state.errors};
  if (!value || value.length === 0) {
    errors[name] = "Store Name is required";
  } else if (value.length > 20) {
    errors[name] = "Store Name should not increase 20 characters";
  } else {
    errors[name] = "";
  }

  this.setState({ [name]: value, errors })
};

<TextField
        //...
        onChange={e => this.onChange(e.target)}
        error={this.state.errors.storeName.length}
        helperText={this.state.errors.storeName}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            storeName: "",
            errors: {
                storeName: "",
                submitError:""
            }
        };
    }
onChange = (name, value) => {
    // this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    let errors = this.state.errors;
    if (!value || value.length === 0) {
        errors[name] = "Store Name is required";
    } else if (value.length > 20) {
        errors[name] = "Store Name should not increase 20 characters";
    } else {
        errors[name] = "";
    }
    this.setState({ errors }) //update state you forget to update your 
    //error state

};



onSubmit = () => {
    //if form is valid then only submit button should work
    const { errors } = this.state
    if (errors.storeName.length) {
        const data = { storeName: this.state.storeName };
        console.log("after submitting", data);
        this.setState({
          errors:{
          ...errors,
          submitError:"your error message"
               }
         })
        return

    }

};
render() {
const{errors}=this.state
    console.log(this.state.errors)// see what you are getting in the console
    return (
        <div>
            <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField
                    id="outlined-basic"
                    label="Store Name"
                    name="storeName"
                    value={this.state.storeName}
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                // error={this.state.errors.storeName.length}
                // helperText={this.state.errors.storeName}
                />
              <p style={{color:'red'}}>{errors.submitError}</p>
            </form>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
                Submit
  </Button>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Sample;
```

Comment: @Thanks for helping me in this query! :)

Comment: Can you assist me what to give in return statement? I want to show an error message below the input field that "store Name is required" in `onSubmit`

Comment: to handle onSubmit I give you suggestion to disable your button when you have error
if you dont want to disable the button and show some custom error what you can do is
create a  new state of error and update it while submit if you have error in the field and show that error below textfieild

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you. I'm using the respective textfield